# Rails link_to with complex HTML inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink

I am trying to use link_to to code the following code block

```
<a class="item-over" href="host.html">
                  <div class="item-time"> <span class="item-month">Jun</span> <span class="item-date">30</span> </div>
                  <div class="item-attending">
                    <div class="item-attending-content"> <span class="user-number">2</span> <span class="user-text">attending</span> </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
```

In the above i want to replace the following text from the DB data

> Jun
>
> 30
>
> 2

My Code:

```
<%= link_to '<div class="item-time"> <span class="item-month">Jun</span> <span class="item-date">30</span> </div><div class="item-attending"><div class="item-attending-content"> <span class="user-number">2</span> <span class="user-text">attending</span> </div></div>'.html_safe, event_path(fevent), {:class => 'item-over'} %>
```

Am not able to add `#{}` in the block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for the block form of `link_to`.

```
<%= link_to event_path(fevent), class: "item-over" do %>
  # complex HTML
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to event_path(fevent), {:class => 'item-over'} do %>
Your HTML here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to be able to use `#{}` inside the string? Then you need to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` around the string.